# Offline webapps in HTML5 - Persist after closing the browser?

Tags: html, offline-caching, offline-mode, offlineapps

With HTML5's offline capabilities is it possible to create an app that will persist after the connection is lost and the browser is closed? Specifically, here's what I'd like to do:

- Connect to the app while online. Download the entire app including a small database it runs on.
- Close the browser and disconnect.
- Open the browser again while offline and load the app from the local cache.

Thanks to Mark Pilgrim's [excellent book](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html) I believe I have an idea of how to accomplish the first step, I'm mainly wondering if the last step is possible. If this is possible, I'm guessing it requires some configuration of the browser. Any settings I should be aware of that aren't obvious?

Thanks very much for any help offered.

Answer (score 0):

The last step should be possible - it just depends on what extent you want to implement it to. To my knowledge it shouldn't require any browser settings. You just have to be aware of the limitations of local storage, which I believe is 5mb max at the moment (for most browsers). Obviously you'd have to perform the checks for such permissions as outlined int the Dive Into Html5 guide you linked.

The quickest and dirtiest way is to simply issue a GET request to your online app. If it responds correctly, then use the online version. If not, use the local cache. Just disguise the timeout/failed response as a 'loading' screen.

Comment: The check to verify if you're online or not makes sense, what I want to know is whether it will even load the page to begin with if the browser has been closed. Will the user need to first connect to the app while online and then leave the page open if they want to use the app offline?

Comment: I think it might actually just load the locally cached content if it's declared in the manifest file if it can't connect to the site.